# ms teams custom app display or overlay our own logo

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm using ms teams ios app with my colleagues.

we found out that in teams app, we can make our custom app.

I'm ios mobile developer and some of colleagues are android.

we want to make custom app which shows an our company logo during using teams.
(which means until we quit the app, our logo overlay teams app)

Is it possible? or any idea would be good!

Comment: It's not possible to overlay Teams logo with our custom Teams app logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to overlay Teams logo with our custom Teams app logo.